# post request on postman

Tags: json, api, post, postman

```
{
"name": "my-sink-connector",
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
"tasks.max": "1",
"topics": "dbserver1.my_sourcedb.Persons",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_destinationdb",
"table.name.format": "Persons"
}
```

shows below error:

> "error_code": 500, "message": "Unrecognized field "connector.class"
> (class
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.entities.CreateConnectorRequest),
> not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "config", "name"])\n at
> [Source:
> (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream);
> line: 10, column: 2] (through reference chain:
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.entities.CreateConnectorRequest["connector.class"]

Answer (score 0):

According to the response you are getting from post-Api, the "connector.class" field is not a valid configuration property for the Request.

Instead, you should include the "connector.class" as part of the "config" field, which is a JSON object that holds the configuration properties.

try below

```
{
  "name": "my-sink-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "dbserver1.my_sourcedb.Persons",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_destinationdb",
    "table.name.format": "Persons"
  }
}
```